# How to prevent App crash when insert/update +10000 rows from JSONArray to SqLite

Tags: android, mysql, database, sqlite, android-cursor

I'm trying to reload all data **from Mysql** Database **to SqLite** Database. I have **10000+** rows and trying to update Sqlite at one command.

**I can update any of my sqlite datatables using these functions, but when it has lot of rows, app crashes**

android.database.CursorWindowAllocationException: Cursor window allocation of 2048 kb failed. # Open Cursors=608 (# cursors opened by this proc=608)

Before reading some articles, I had this done with ContentValues, I found that using SQLiteStatement increases insert/update speed a lot.

**Here is how I done it:**

KeyTypePair includes column names and types like this, **12 columns**:

```
public static final String[][] KEYS_TYPES = {
        new String[] { "id_field", "int"},
        new String[] { "text", "string" }
        ................. and so on..................
}
```

**DBDatabase.java**

```
private SQLiteDatabase db;
```

**This gets 10000+ rows from mysql and tries to insert/update to sqlite**

```
public void addAll(JSONArray ARRAY, String TABLE, String IDFIELD, String[][] KEYS_TYPES) {
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    String sqlPrepared = sqlPrepared(KEYS_TYPES);

    if(doesTableExist(db, TABLE)) {
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject ROW = ARRAY.getJSONObject(i);

                int id = getId(ROW, IDFIELD);

                String where = " WHERE " + IDFIELD + "=" + id;

                add(ROW, TABLE, IDFIELD, id, sqlPrepared, where, KEYS_TYPES);
            }
            long difference = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
            Log.e("add all timing", new Long(difference).toString());
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            voids.debugMsg(context, "SQLite addAll ERROR: " + e.toString());
        }
    } else {
        voids.debugMsg(context, "TABLE " + TABLE + " NOT EXIST, LETS TRY AGAIN..");
        createTable(db, TABLE);
        addAll(ARRAY, TABLE, IDFIELD, KEYS_TYPES);
    }
}
```

**This will do the actual insertion**

```
public void add(JSONObject object, String TABLE, String ID, int id, String sqlPrepared, String where, String[][] keyTypePair) {
    db.beginTransaction();
    String sql = "";
    if(dataExist(TABLE, ID, id)) {
        sql = "UPDATE " + TABLE + " SET " + sqlPrepared + where;
    } else {
        sql = "INSERT INTO " + TABLE + " SET " + sqlPrepared;
    }

    try {
        SQLiteStatement stmt = db.compileStatement(sql);
        stmt = bindValues(keyTypePair, stmt, object);
        stmt.execute();
    } finally {

    }
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    db.endTransaction();
}
```

**This creates partial prepared String for UPDATE AND INSERT**

```
public String sqlPrepared(String[][] keyTypePair) {
    String columnString = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < keyTypePair.length; i++) {
        String[] pair = keyTypePair[i];
        String KEY = pair[0];
        if(keyTypePair.length!=i+1) {
            columnString += KEY + "=?, ";
        } else {
            columnString += KEY + "=?";
        }

    }
    columnString += "";
    return columnString;
}
```

**This is just for getting id from JSONObject**

```
private int getId(JSONObject OBJECT, String ID) {
    int id = 0;
    try {
        id = OBJECT.getInt(ID);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("DBDatabase ERROR: ", "ERROR WHILE TRYING TO ADD TO SQLite: "+e.toString());
    }
    return id;
}
```

**This checks if row exist in SqLite Database**

```
public boolean dataExist(String TABLE, String IDFIELD, int ID) {
    boolean exist = false;
    String[] columns = {IDFIELD};
    Cursor cursor =
            db.query(TABLE,
                    columns, // b. column names
                    IDFIELD + " = ?", // c. selections
                    new String[]{String.valueOf(ID)}, // d. selections args
                    null, // e. group by
                    null, // f. having
                    null, // g. order by
                    null); // h. limit
    if (cursor.getCount()>0) {
        exist = true;
    }
    return exist;
}
```

**Here is what I got into logcat when app crashes:**

```
08-24 17:02:06.137    9522-9522/.DBService E/Zygote﹕ MountEmulatedStorage()
08-24 17:02:06.137    9522-9522/.DBService E/Zygote﹕ v2
08-24 17:02:06.167    9522-9522/.DBService E/SELinux﹕ [DEBUG] get_category: variable seinfo: default sensitivity: NULL, cateogry: NULL
08-24 17:02:13.687    9522-9522/.DBService E/CursorWindow﹕ Could not allocate CursorWindow '/data/data/my.app/databases/myDB' of size 2097152 due to error -12.
08-24 17:02:13.697    9522-9522/.DBService E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: .DBService, PID: 9522
android.database.CursorWindowAllocationException: Cursor window allocation of 2048 kb failed. # Open Cursors=608 (# cursors opened by this proc=608)
        at android.database.CursorWindow.<init>(CursorWindow.java:108)
        at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.clearOrCreateWindow(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:198)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.clearOrCreateWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:301)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:139)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:133)
        at my.app.MyDatabase.dataExist(MyDatabase.java:569)
        at my.app.MyDatabase.add(MyDatabase.java:392)
        at my.app.MyDatabase.addAll(MyDatabase.java:407)
        at my.app.MyReceiver$1.onSuccess(MyReceiver.java:37)
        at my.app.SocketManager$1.onPostExecute(SocketManager.java:121)
        at my.app.SocketManager$1.onPostExecute(SocketManager.java:58)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `dataExist()` you need to close the cursor before returning i.e.

```
public boolean dataExist(String TABLE, String IDFIELD, int ID) {
    boolean exist = false;
    String[] columns = {IDFIELD};
    Cursor cursor =
            db.query(TABLE,
                    columns, // b. column names
                    IDFIELD + " = ?", // c. selections
                    new String[]{String.valueOf(ID)}, // d. selections args
                    null, // e. group by
                    null, // f. having
                    null, // g. order by
                    null); // h. limit
    if (cursor.getCount()>0) {
        exist = true;
    }
    cursor.close();
    return exist;
}
```

Comment: Wow, this did the trick. Little question about increasing speed, is there anything to do to increase insert/update time still? Thanks a lot for this. @jgm

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing more details about your setup.  The only obvious thing is to ensure that you don't have any indices set up on your target table until after you have completed the inserts, as they will cause multiple writes for each insert.